# How can i write a text file to my smartphone flash drive connected in the usb?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The problem is that when I connect my smartphone to the usb I see on my pc explorer G3 I don't see a new drive letter like C: D: E: F: G:

So as a path how do I know where to write the text file to ? How do I get the flash drive letter of my smartphone that is connected to the usb ?

I tried this now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Write_to_flash_drive
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string pathtowrite = @"G3\Internal storage";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(pathtowrite + "\\test.txt");
            w.Write("test");
            w.Close();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And got exception:

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\C-Sharp\Write to flash drive\Write to flash drive\Write to flash drive\bin\Debug\G3\Internal storage\test.txt'.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/drive-letter-for-mtp-connection-under-windows

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your smartphone is a LG G3, you have to select MTP protocol when connecting it to the usb port : [here is how](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/LG-G3.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my)

Windows is going to assign you a letter and that way you are going to set the letter as a path and write a file as you would do in C#.[Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Comment: When I connect my phone to the usb I don't have any options to select and I slready set it to be on USB debugging mode. I don't have any MTP mode protocol. And I could use before eclipse java android code to write applications to my phone. It's working fine. The problem is with the c# winforms to find the path to the phone. G3\Internal storage is not a valid path.